# Windows Phone 8 emulator Network issues

Tags: networking, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

First of all, I admit I am new in Windows Phone 8 application.So do not rate it as low.
So please forgive me.

I have created WCF service, I am getting the results but when I run in windows phone, its returning error: "System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException", and I know why this is happening, it is occuring due to network problems.

My emulator is not getting netowrk from my system, I have Wifi network, and if there is no internet in my system, in case I have given static IP. That is the problem.
How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue as well. However as someone else pointed out on the official forums it didn't work if you had a static IP for your PC set up in your router. Removing it and let the DHCP assign my PC an IP solved the issue for me.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wptools/thread/28c8316a-80e8-4fd9-b323-c07a2265d069/)

Answer (score 2):

You may need to change your firewall settings or your proxy settings.

As Mohammed Tau said below you need to remove your static IP and use a router which gives you a generated IP. It's either that, or as suggested in this question (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/3e40751b-f888-45b1-961f-b1a0f23a3027/windows-phone-8-emulator-internet-connectivity-issue?forum=wptools)

"It would appear that the phone emulator requires you to have a second network adapter to dedicate to this purpose."

"Basically, it appears that for some odd reason it won't properly work unless the phone has the same MAC address as the network adapter. However, we can't just set it to use the same MAC address because address conflicts are very very bad. So, we need a second adapter that we can dedicate to the Phone emulator. "

Good luck!

Comment: I had turned of firewall and given IP address in my service reference, can you give me solution about that router issue and DHCP, I have the problem like that.Thnx for ur reply