# Windows Phone 8 network issue about developer account

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created windows phone 8 application, but still I have no certificate or developer account, so when I install applications on a device, now in my system, net is connected through LAN(airtel), and in my windows phone, network is wifi(airtel), both are same. Now the problem is whenever I change the network of my windows device, the app doesn't run. Do I need developer account? And if I get it, shall I able to run my windows app on any network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you're gonna test in your device you have to `Developer Unlock` your device to deploy the applications. You can do this by using the tool from VS, `Windows Phone Developer Registration` through one of your live accounts.

But to test inn the `emulator` you don't have to. Yep you can test in any network, but make sure the you can see the emulator running the `Hyper-v Manager`.

Look in here for more:

[Windows Phone 8 emulator Network issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029441/)

[Windows Phone 8 emulator can't connect to the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13159947/windows-phone-8-emulator-cant-connect-to-the-internet?rq=1)

Hope it helps!

Comment: anonshankar,thanks but I have unlocked windows phone thourgh my microsoft account, but I am not able to run on other network!!

Comment: anonshankar, I can test app on device but on the same network that is same as my system network.Please guide me

Comment: The problem is the emulator takes the default network as it's. So you have to remove the unwanted network from the HyperV Manager. 
Goto Hyper-V Manager > Virtual Switch Manager > Tick the Remove Checkbox for the network you wanted to remove. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13149509/windows-phone-8-emulator-error-something-happened-while-creating-a-switch

Comment: anonshankar,ok man thank you so so much,then shall I able to run app on windows device on any network??rply

Comment: anonshankar, can you answer me one more question, brother??

Comment: Yes sure. What's that?

Comment: anonshankar, I have created WCF service,I have hosted it in local IIS, and I have called this WCF service in windows phone, so whenever I shut down my system, the app does not run on device. What is the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: and yesterday you suggested me that, about emulator. "Should I select 'Internal Network' in virtual switch manager?"thanks!!